# Adding print statements with % crashes my program?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Every time I'm using `print "in some_function. x: %s" % x` to debug some python program (typically Python 2.5 or Python 2.6), if `x` is a tuple, my program crashes. Why? How can I avoid this when adding prints to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when `x` is a tuple, Python assumes that the elements of the tuple are arguments to format the string. For example, if I do

```
>>> "one: %s two: %s" % ('fish','chips')
'one: fish two: chips'
```

If you want Python to substitute the entire tuple, pass the arguments to the string as a tuple with one element:

```
>>> "This is a tuple: %s" % (('fish','chips'),)
"This is a tuple: ('fish', 'chips')"
```

The comma at the end distinguishes a construction like `(x,)` from `(x)`. The first is a tuple with one element, while the second is simply `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the actual argument on the right-hand side of `%` is supposed to be a tuple, because the string on the left-hand side can have multiple placeholders for elements of the tuple to fill in. The single-argument version is actually a special case. So when you place your `x` there and it is actually a tuple, Python assumes you're providing several arguments to fill in the placeholders - only there aren't several placeholders, hence the exception.

Putting `(x,)` fixes it because that now makes the argument a tuple containing a single element, which is itself a tuple.